# FreeImage library not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, dynamic

Installed FreeImage through MacPorts. Everything looked to be OK, but when I builded my app and tried to launch on other computer where is no MacPorts and no FreeImage installed it says

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreeimage.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/development/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/freeimage-dxsornyaxqlkyubqwsrlkgszvxhy/Build/Products/Debug/freeimage.app/Contents/MacOS/freeimage
  Reason: image not found
```

Shouldn't it copy library files together with my project? I added them to my project's build phases "Copy files" list. They are being copied to my app's bundle. But when I try to link them, I get same error. I don't know why but app is still looking for library in /opt/local/lib. How can I fix it so that I could use FreeImage at my project and run it at any computer?

Comment: The OS is looking for the dynamic libraries in `/opt/local/lib` but you have them inside your bundle, hence they are not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install through MacPorts the library is installed in /opt/local/lib, not in your project path. Even if you copy the whole project, the *dylib libraries won't be copied because they are usually in /opt/local/lib.

I believe you have two options here: install FreeImage in every computer that you want to run your application, or copy the libfreeimage.3.dylib to the same folder where your binnary is and, if both systems are similar, that should work. If the two computers are different in terms of operating system version, hardware architecture, etc... then probably the .dylib that you have won't be compatible for the other computer.

Another thing you might want to consider is to modify your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable, which specifies the paths in which the OS will look for libraries when linking. See [**this answer**](https://superuser.com/a/282451/148055) for more information.